# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 hangs on boot

Tags: boot

I will try to make this as concise as possible.

- Gigabyte GA-G31M-ES2L built ca. 2010
- Ran Ubuntu 16.04 for last couple of years
- Upgraded to 18.04, now hangs at the purple screen immediately
  after the mouse cursor appears in lower right
- Sounds like graphics problem, but ...
- Created Live USB stick and, after spending way too much time on the "dreaded Gigabyte boot from USB problem", can now boot from
  that
- Ubuntu runs fine from USB stick -> graphics ok??
- Installed Ubuntu many times from USB stick, nothing worked
- Eventually ran from USB stick and formatted the HDD, reinstalled from USB
- Still has the exact same problem.

Nothing I do seems to change the boot from HDD problem, but it seems to work normally from the USB stick.

I know the basics of linux, but I am not super familiar with low level fixes.

Any suggestions on where to go?  Reading the forums suggests it might be the old graphics processor (no external card, just the VGA built into the motherboard) but it works from the stick, suggesting the graphics is ok.

Comment: What kind of graphics is built into the motherboard? Is it Intel, ATI, Nvidia, or something else?

Comment: In the link suggested by karel, you can get to a terminal to fix things.  I don't even get that far.

Comment: As for the graphics, I'm not sure, there is no separate gpu, I believe it is built into the main processor.

Comment: @karel switching to lightdm is, at best, a workaround for the problem... not a fix. A very common solution is in my answer. Wayland :-(

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

**Update #1:**

Based on additional information from the user, I'd recommend that we check the file system to make sure it's ok.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Ok, I did this, and fsck showed no errors.  Also uncommented WaylandEnable=false and seems to still be working

Comment: @mGand Did you previously follow karel's answer, and change the display manager from gdm3 to lightdm? If so, you should try and change it back to gdm3.

Answer (score 0):

So before I saw this answer, I somehow accidentally fixed it.  After booting to recovery mode, I did a system summary, then I decided to look at the flash option since I'd never tried it before, don't have a file to burn. I expected a cancel option or some such, but the only one was power off.  I changed nothing, saved nothing and pressed power off.  The recovery menu reappeared, then console lines started overwriting the menu in random fashion, then it powered off.  Powered it back on, and all of a sudden it is working.  I've booted several times now and it seems to work fine.  I really don't like it when this kind of thing happens, but I'm not inclined to go digging and risk breaking it again.  Thanks for your suggestions.  I may go look at /etc/gdm3/custom.conf but not sure if I'll change it.
Thanks again.
Mike

Comment: Please see Update #1 in my previous answer.